# Access - Use Totals Function

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, aggregate-functions

Hello and good morning,

I am back again with ANOTHER question I am stumped on. I feel like a failure.

Currently, I am using the Access Query Wizard to build a relatively large query. I am pulling from 7 different tables from an outside data source.

I currently have one query (sqONE) which will return to me all of the functions an employee can do. An employee can do more than one function, and a function can be done by more than one. I am using the totals function here.

Then, I have another query (sqTWO)which looks at all the times that an employee did something wrong (i.e., an error). It uses sqONE and then lists every error and what the error was coded as (error number, error description).

However, I now want to do a THIRD query (sqTHREE) which will calculate how much time the employee needed to fix that error. The problem is they might do half an hour here...2 hours there...4 hours here...all on the same error number. Thus, I get an enormous table which lists

```
    EmployeeName | EmployeeNumber | FunctionName| FunctionNumber | ErrorName | ErrorNumber | RepairTime
```

For every single time that someone spent any time fixing an error. So I might have one hundred repeating values of the columns listed above if it took somebody one hundred attempts, at a half hour a piece, to fix their error. All I want to see is the TOTAL repair time for that error.

Can somebody please help or advise on how I might be able to do this? I am trying to use the TOTALS function in Access but get the error that I cannot because I am selecting * from sqTWO.

Any help would be immensely appreciated. Thank you to everyone who takes the time to help me. I really appreciate it.

Comment: `Currently, I am using the Access Query Wizard to build a relatively large query`. Nothing good comes after that. Please build your own queries, and share the SQL. Not everything can be done with the wizard.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I am trying but I don't know how to yet. I can post the SQL that Access is helping me generate. I have been looking at different resources but have been unsuccessful unless I use the wizard to help get me started..

Comment: @TonyKelly Posting the generated SQL is a good start. Once the problems have been identified and sorted out, you can compare what was generated to what actually works. That should get you a bit further along the "learning SQL" path. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your SQL code:

The first thing you can do is put all the field names in your sqTwo query.  You can't use `*` which is the wild card for 'All Fields' when you are trying to do a total.

And the other thing you may have to keep in mind (and I'm not sure since you didn't give us your code) is that if you do aggregates of your tables/queries using `Group By` in Access, sometimes you have to write the results to a temp table before you can call that dataset into another query. You may not be there yet, but it looks like you are heading in that direction.  Just something to be aware of.

Third thing... you might want to consider avoiding the Totals function and use the `Group By` functionality with a Sum function.  But that may be a 'next level' thing for a beginning SQL programmer.

Comment: I took your advice and manually composed my SQL

I took the sqTWO query and instead "blew it up" by not selecting by * but by manually doing each field, grouping by, and then "SUM" on the time spent portion.